# How to render variable number of Long Text fields as JavaScript tabs with custom tab names

Tags: 7, theming, entities

The usual way to produce JavaScript tabs is by listing the tabs titles in an HTML list, then list the corresponding contents in divs, then use jQuery to display the content of the current active tab. See [this tutorial](http://www.lessthanweb.com/blog/simple-css-tabs-with-jquery) for more info.

What is the best recipe to generate this html and allow this type functionality? The number of tabs and tab names can vary from node to another.

The best I can think of is creating a field of type "List (Text)" for the tabs titles, and another unlimited "Long Text" field for the tabs contents. Then edit the node template for that content type to output the contents within that HTML structure mentioned about.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, without writing a single line of code. Here you are: http://previousnext.com.au/blog/introducing-field-collection-tabs-formatter

Used [Field Collection Tab formatter](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_tabs) module.

> Field collection tabs provides a field formatter that allows you to
>   output a multi value field collection field as a tabset, with one tab
>   per field collection item.You can optionally choose a field from the
>   field collection item to be used as the tab title.